# В lambda функции не меняется значении переменной

Tags: java, firebase, lambda

Осваиваю firebase, хочу реализовать приложение так, чтобы у каждого пользователя был уникальный логин. Для этого во время регистрации проверяю, есть ли в базе данных пользователь с таким логином:

```
public boolean validateLogin(String login) {
       AtomicReference<Boolean> validate = new AtomicReference<>();
       db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("login", login).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> validate.set(task.getResult().size() == 0));
       return validate.get();
    }
```

Но функция возвращает пустое значение...

Comment: Что делает этот код: `task.getResult().size() == 0`? Не должно быть `!=`?

Comment: Проверка, есть ли документы, в которых поле login равно введенному пользователем логину: если размер полученного массива равен нулю, значит таких документов нет

Comment: Тогда вы вводите существующий логин и получаете `false`. Что-нибудь не так?

Comment: Такое предположение: если `addCompleteLIstener` асинхронный, то вы просто получаете результат до того как его обновила база данных.

Comment: Если это правда, то у вас смешаны асинхронный код Firebase и вам синхронный код `return`. Эта архитектура не будет работать. Весь код, который пользуется результатом выборки должен быть погружен в колбек. Следовательно, вы не можете написать функцию которая возвращает результат.

Comment: Чтоб решить проблему именно с асинхронностью замените `AtomicReference` на `CompletableFuture ` и `validate.set` на `validate.complete`. Только имейте ввиду, что у вас тут в коде гонки. Если два пользователя одновременно введут несуществующий пароль, проверка пройдет успешно у обоих.

Comment: Правильный способ сделать уникальность это использовать security rules, как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique